# Failed: Unexpected value 'WidgetGeneralSettings' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm trying to test this component but I had this error

```
fdescribe('DateTimeWidgetComponent', () => {
  let component: DateTimeWidgetComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DateTimeWidgetComponent>;
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [DateTimeWidgetComponent],
      imports: [FlexLayoutModule, WidgetGeneralSettings]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));
```

this is the classe called in test

export class WidgetGeneralSettings {

```
  title: string;
  backgroundColor: string;
  color: string;
  style: string;

}
```